# Loading .coverage files from coverage.py into IntelliJ IDEA/PyCharm's coverage view

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I have `.coverage` files indicating code coverage of my Django project produced by [coverage.py](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/):

```
coverage run --branch --source='.' manage.py test style
```

I can produce nice HTML reports with `coverage html`, but I'd really prefer to take advantage of IDEA's coverage view to indicate coverage in my project while I work on it.

I can't use IntelliJ's "Run with Coverage" command to generate the coverage data in the standard way. *(Please take this for granted; I may ask a second question later about my reasons why.)*

Is there any way I can import the `.coverage` files produces by coverage.py into IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 10):

This is possible, at least as long as you run `coverage` in the root directory of your project.

First you need convert the `.coverage` file to `coverage.xml` by running `coverage xml`. Then it's just a matter of going to the *Analyze* menu, selecting "Show Code Coverage Data" and adding the XML file.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: This was useful, but it shows 0% everywhere, should the paths be relative or absolute?

Comment: The paths must be absolute, or relative to the project root. The last two paragraph here explains more: https://json-tricks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#running-tests

Comment: I had to replace all the `filename="file.py"` tags in the xml file with absolute file paths to get pycharm to do the coverage highlighting properly.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Intellij CE 2017.1.5. It wont let me select the coverage.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, and now with pycharm 2.7 you should go to Tools -> Show Code Coverage Data and add new File